# How to display the output as below using Pandas Data Frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the Data Frame as below:

```
version   Numbers

4229    234
6065    567
9209    8910
2304    1122
4229    3344
6065    5566
9209    1234
2304    6789
4229    1376
6065    1111
9209    2222
2304    145
4229    267
6065    345
9209    557
2304    778


Need Output as Below ( grouped by version numbers):

4229    234
        3344
        1376
        267
6065    
        567
        5566
        1111
        345
9209    
        8910
        1234
        2222
        557
2304    
        1122
        6789
        145
        778
```

I tried df.groupby['version'] but this does not give the desired output.

Could you please help me here?

Answer (score 1):

If there is multuiple columns like 2, use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) for `MultiIndex`. Here `Categorical` is used sorted categorival for ordering by original column:

```
df['a'] = 1

df['version'] = pd.Categorical(df['version'], 
                               ordered=True, 
                               categories=df['version'].unique())
df1 = df.set_index(['version', 'Numbers']).sort_index(level=0, sort_remaining=False)
print (df1)
                 a
version Numbers   
4229    234      1
        3344     1
        1376     1
        267      1
6065    567      1
        5566     1
        1111     1
        345      1
9209    8910     1
        1234     1
        2222     1
        557      1
2304    1122     1
        6789     1
        145      1
        778      1
```